# How can I show filtered results based on button click?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array created from a .csv file that I show all of on initial page load, but after a button click, I would like to display only the results of the name of the building the user clicks on.

**Here is the html code:**

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="StaffListCtrl">
            <div class="small-12 columns" >
                <h1 class="">The Public Schools of Petoskey Staff</h1>
                <header ng-include="'pages/header.html'"></header>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-2 columns"><h4>BUILDING</h4></div>
                    <div class="small-3 columns"><h4>NAME</h4></div>
                    <div class="small-2 columns"><h4>PHONE</h4></div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns"><h4>EMAIL</h4></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row"  id="centralBuilding" data-ng-model="buildingName.central" ng-repeat="person in staff">
                    <div class="small-2 columns">{{ person.getBuilding() }}</div>
                    <div class="small-3 columns">{{ person.getFirstName() }} {{ person.getLastName() }}</div>
                    <div class="small-2 columns">{{ person.getPhone() }}</div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns">{{ person.getEmail() }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer ng-include="'pages/footer.html'"></footer>
        </div>
```

**Here is the header.html code:**

```
<div class="row">
    <button class="round" id="building1">Building1</button>
    <button class="round" id="building2">Building2</button>
    <button class="round" id="building3">Building3</button>
</div>
```

Here is my AngularJS code:

**app.js:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('staffApp', []);
})();
```

**controller.js:**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('staffApp')
        .controller('StaffListCtrl', listStaff);

    function listStaff($scope) {
        $scope.filters = {};
        $scope.staff = setStaffData();
    }
})();
```

Comment: can you just give me a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the best Fiddle I can provide. The answer below seems close, but I still can't get it to work. I think my controller logic is flawed?
https://jsfiddle.net/BackPacker777/8g2g1pww/2/

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BackPacker777/8g2g1pww/3/

Answer (score 1):

If person is an object like

```
var person = {
     building: "",
     firstName: "",
     lastName: "",
     phone:"",
     email: ""
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row"  id="centralBuilding" data-ng-model="buildingName.central" ng-repeat="person in staff | filter : {building = filterBuilding}">
     <div class="small-2 columns">{{ person.getBuilding() }}</div>
     <div class="small-3 columns">{{ person.getFirstName() }} {{ person.getLastName() }}</div>
     <div class="small-2 columns">{{ person.getPhone() }}</div>
     <div class="small-4 columns">{{ person.getEmail() }}</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <button class="round" id="building1" ng-click="filterByBuilding('Building1')>Building1</button>
     <button class="round" id="building2" filterByBuilding('Building2'>Building2</button>
     <button class="round" id="building3" filterByBuilding('Building3'>Building3</button>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function filterByBuilding(building){
     $scope.filterBuilding = building;
}
```

Comment: This works for the filtering by building, but how do I ensure it still shows all employees on initial page load, then filters based on button click?

Comment: Normally, when you are on the initital page, everything is showed because "filterBuilding" is undefined

Comment: "filterBuilding" will only be defined after clicking on one of the three buttons

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle which you have given I have found only a slight mistake

- Instead of $scope.filterByBuilding you have mentioned as `$scope.filterBuilding`
- Used `data/staff2.csv` instead of `staffList.csv`

Take a look at this working demo

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCEbII0n9YQrVSw7Mrpt?p=preview)**

**script**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('staffApp', [])
        .controller('StaffListCtrl', MainCtrl);

        function MainCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.staff = setStaffData();

        $scope.filterByBuilding = function(building) {
            $scope.filterBuilding = building;
        };
    }
})();
```

**html**

```
<body ng-app="staffApp">
    <div class="row" data-ng-controller="StaffListCtrl">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
                <h1 class="">Staff List</h1>

            <div class="row">
                <button class="round" id="buildingA" ng-click="filterByBuilding('buildingA')">Building A</button>
                <button class="round" id="buildingB" ng-click="filterByBuilding('buildingB')">Building B</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-2 columns">
                    <h4>BUILDING</h4>
                </div> 
                <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <h4>NAME</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="small-2 columns">
                    <h4>PHONE</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="small-4 columns">
                    <h4>EMAIL</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="person in staff | filter:{building:filterBuilding}">
                <div class="small-2 columns">{{ person.getBuilding() }}</div>
                <div class="small-3 columns">{{ person.getFirstName() }} {{ person.getLastName() }}</div>
                <div class="small-2 columns">{{ person.getPhone() }}</div>
                <div class="small-4 columns">{{ person.getEmail() }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```